# Replace old intent with new on while app is in background in Android 11

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a scenario in which i need to cancel old intent.

1. App receive a call while app is in background.
2. App try to start new activity by using intent, also setting putExtra(value) but activity does not come in foreground due to Android 11(It is ok), however startactivity method is being called.
3. App again receive call from another user, now i intentionally open app, but old activity with old user data(intentextra) is being shown.

is there any way to cancel previous activity? or override

Thanks

Comment: Do you try to add android:launchMode flags in the manifest file? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode

Comment: Yes, I am using singleTask as launch mode. Actually when i start activity in background, oncreate method is not called(That is expected), but when again i start activity in background and then open app, i see old data that i put in intent.putextra

Comment: Try to check new data in onNewIntent().

According to documentation singleTask:
.. if activity already exists, the system routes the intent to existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new one.